# Derivative of an integral? $f(y) = \frac{d}{dy} F(y) = \color{red}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}}\Phi'(\sqrt{y})$

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, derivatives

Am I right to say if I differenciate an integral, I get back the thing inside the integral?

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int f(x) \, dx = f(x)$$

Then why is it in the below question,

[image]

The last line marked by the arrow ...

$$\frac{d}{dy} F(y) = \frac{d}{dy} (2 \Phi(\sqrt{y})-1) = \frac{d}{dy} (2(\int^{\sqrt{y}}_{-\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-u^2/2} 
\; du)) = 2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-y/2}$$

How do I get the extra $\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}$ part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$F(y)=2\Phi (\sqrt y)$. By the chain rule, you get:$$f(y)=F'(y)=2\cdot \Phi '(\sqrt y) \cdot \frac{d}{dy}[\sqrt y]=\frac{\Phi'(\sqrt y)}{\sqrt y}.$$

The issue with your proof is that, when you take the derivative of a function of the form $$H(x)=\int _a ^{f(x)} g,$$
you are considering a composition: $$h(t)=\int _a ^t g , \quad H(x)=(h\circ f)(x),$$
so the derivative of $H$ is:

$$H'(x)=(h'\circ f) (x) \cdot f'(x)=g(f(x))f'(x).$$

Comment: Did I do something wrong tho? If I have $2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-y/2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} = \color{red}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi y}} e^{-y/2}$. Have an extra $2$?

Comment: You just forgot a $2$: $\frac{d}{dx}[x^p]=p x ^{p-1}$.

Comment: Err ... here $x^p$ is the integral? But a derivative of an integral is just whats inside the integral (except $u$ becomes $\sqrt{y}$)?

Comment: See edited answer; I was just explaining why are you missing a two: because $\frac{\text d}{\text d x }\sqrt x=\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}$.